# How can I point tox to all python versions in a portable way (eg. without hard-coding the paths in tox.ini)?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tox

I'd like to run tox for python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, etc. and am looking for a way to do this that doesn't involve hard-coding the python paths into a project's tox.ini like I'm currently doing:

```
[testenv:py27]
    basepython=/usr/prog/python/2.7.5/bin/python
```

since this breaks when run on a different machine. Does tox have some global config file where I can set this (didn't find the answer in ~/.tox/ or in the manual)?

Thanks

-Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just name the Python version you want. Tox will figure out the path.

```
basepython = python2.7
```

If that doesn't work for you, Tox supports environment substitutions inside curly braces.

`{envname}` The name of the virtual environment

`{envpython}` Path to the virtual Python interpreter

`{envdir}` Directory of the virtualenv hierarchy

More info in the [Tox documentation](http://tox.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#substitutions-for-virtualenv-related-sections)